# How to get LoggedIn User Api Token and display at user account page for Laravel API

Tags: laravel, authentication, access-token, laravel-sanctum

I have created an API for my Laravel Application. An API Token is created for a user when the User Creates an Account. I want to retrieve the API Token and Display it at the user's profile Page so that the user can use the Token to Authenticate the API URL in order to fetch the Data and display the data on their own website.

I have tried many ways but I can't get the token to show in the view.

I have tried the following but didn't work

```
$user = Auth::user();
$token = $user->tokens->first();
$token = $user->tokens()->where('personal_access_tokens.name', 'myapi')->first();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I have created an API for my Laravel Application. An API Token is created for a user when the User Creates an Account. I want to retrieve the API Token and Display it at the user's profile Page so that the user can use the Token to Authenticate the API URL in order to fetch the Data and display the data on their own web site.
I have tried many ways but I can't get the token to show in the view.

I have tried the following but didn't work

```
$user = Auth::user();
$token = $user->tokens->first();
$token = $user->tokens()->where('personal_access_tokens.name', 'myapi')->first();
```